# PHP - Regex to remove the string between parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a filename into 3 parts here.

Example: Artist - Title ( Mix ) or Artist - Title [ Mix ]

My code so far.

```
preg_match('/^(.*) - (.*)\.mp3$/', $mp3, $matches);
$artist = $matches[1];
$title = $matches[2];
echo "File: $mp3" . "Artist: $artist" . "\n" . "Title: $title" . "<br />";
```

This is getting me the Artist and the Title. The problem I have is that Mix is either between () or [ ]. I'm not sure how to modify my regex in order to capture that part.

Comment: Your pattern does not work so far. You might not try it yet.

Comment: I tried this and its working. So far I get o/p as Artist: artist Title: title (mix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a 100% regex solution, but I think it's the most elegant you'll get.

Basically, you want to capture `(anything)` or `[anything]`, which can be represented as `\(.*\)|\[.*\]`. Then, make that a capture group, and double escape it, to get `(\\(.*\\)|\\[.*\\])`.

Unfortunately, this captures the `()` or `[]` as well, so you have to strip those; I simply used `substr($matches[3], 1, -1)` to do the job:

```
$mp3 = "Jimmy Cross - I Want My Baby Back (Remix).mp3";
preg_match('/^(.*) - (.*) (\\(.*\\)|\\[.*\\])\.mp3$/', $mp3, $matches);
$artist = $matches[1];
$title = $matches[2];
$mix = substr($matches[3], 1, -1);
echo "File: $mp3" . "<br/>" . "Artist: $artist" . "<br/>" . "Title: $title" . "<br />" . "Mix: $mix" . "<br />";
```

Prints out:

> File: Jimmy Cross - I Want My Baby Back (Remix).mp3 
>   Artist: Jimmy Cross 
>   Title: I Want My Baby Back 
>   Mix: Remix

Comment: This works good. But what if i have a situation where i just have Artist - Title. It fails. Also the remix is printed as (remix). I'll try to work around this to fix it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: My bad, i completely missed the substring you used to eliminate the (). Thanks a ton, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `'/^(.*) - ([^\(\[]*) [\(\[] ([^\)\]]*) [\)\]]\.mp3$/'`

However, this may not be the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use named subpatterns for this specific case.

```
$mp3s = array(
    "Billy May & His Orchestra - T'Ain't What You Do.mp3",
    "Shirley Bassey - Love Story [Away Team Mix].mp3",
    "Björk - Isobel (Portishead remix).mp3",
    "Queen - Another One Bites the Dust (remix).mp3"
);

$pat = '/^(?P<Artist>.+?) - (?P<Title>.*?)( *[\[\(](?P<Mix>.*?)[\]\)])?\.mp3$/';

foreach ($mp3s as $mp3) {
    preg_match($pat,$mp3,$res);
    foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
        if (is_numeric($k)) unset($res[$k]);
        // this is for sanitizing the array for the output
    }
    if (!isset($res['Mix'])) $res['Mix'] = NULL;
    // this is for the missing Mix'es
    print_r($res);
}
```

will output

```
Array (
    [Artist] => Billy May & His Orchestra
    [Title] => T'Ain't What You Do
    [Mix] => 
)
Array (
    [Artist] => Shirley Bassey
    [Title] => Love Story
    [Mix] => Away Team Mix
)
Array (
    [Artist] => Björk
    [Title] => Isobel
    [Mix] => Portishead remix
)
Array (
    [Artist] => Queen
    [Title] => Another One Bites the Dust
    [Mix] => remix
)
```